# Strict regular expression for shared/network folder

Tags: regex, path, shared-directory

I'm trying to limit user's input to a valid shared folder path like

`\\\computer-name\drive\optional_folder1\optional_folder2\`

1. Starts with 2 slashes followed by computer name, single slash, and drive letter. (I got this part down)
2. Ends with 0 or 1 slash.
3. Can have zero or more single slash followed by folder name (\folder).
4. No multiple slashes besides the first one.

I've tried to look around and around and make my own regex, but I can't find the perfect answer. This is my current regex:

`^((\\{2})([A-Za-z -._]+)(\\{1})([A-Za-z -._]+))(\\{1}([A-Za-z .-_])+)*(\\?)$`

Any hints will be appreciated.

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've simplified it a bit:

```
^(\\)(\\[\w\.-_]+){2,}(\\?)$
```

So basically you want to have

```
^(\\)              # start with slash
(\\[\w\.-_]+)      # followed by group of slash and name
{2,}               # which should be two or more times
(\\?)$             # last slash(es)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mD2yL7/110

Comment: That's a perfect solution and a better way to look at it. Thank you. You've taught me how to simplify the criteria.

Comment: Thanks) Hope it will work, let me know in case of problems, cause comparing to your pattern you don't escape slashes and dots. So there could be issues with your regex engine.

Comment: This regex failed, `String path = "String path = "\\\\WIN-OTPNOBLC0AQ.myhacks.test.com\\sysvol"`. Any idea why would this be?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to escape dots (`.`) by `\\.`?

Comment: @streetturtle instead of escaping dots specifically, can I instead use a regex that says 'any character'? I want to first validate that the input is composed of: 2 slashes + 1 word (which can be FQDN/NetBIOSname/IPaddress) + slash + share name

Comment: it doesn't pass things like \\c$\somethingelse\ which is valid